# Why I can not get zoom in and out effect immediately but have to resize window first

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to OpenGL. I encounter a problem. Why I can not get zoom in and out effect in OpenGL immediately but have to resize window first and then I can see the image plotted become smaller or larger.

I am so sorry that I do not which part of program should I provide to clarify this problem.

I think the problem may be caused by mouse function?

```
void glutMouseWheel(int wheel_number, int direction, int x, int y)
{
if (direction == 1)
    zoomFactor = 0.5*zoomFactor;
 else
     zoomFactor = 2* zoomFactor;
     glutPostRedisplay();
}



void reshape(int w, int h)
{

glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-0.001*zoomFactor, 0.001*zoomFactor, -0.001*zoomFactor, 0.001*zoomFactor, -100, 100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
 }
```

As you see I define a double zoomFactor to adjust the orthogonal volume to zoom the image. It should be fine, but I do not know why I still encounter this problem.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to provide you a solution when you haven't provided us with _any_ tangible information or relevant code?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious sorry about that, I just modified my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you can change `zoomFactor` all you want but it won't get applied to the OpenGL state (via the code in `resize()`) until you resize the window.

The `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of `glutMouseWheel()` ***will not*** cause the `glutReshapeFunc()` callback to run.  It only schedules a `glutDisplayFunc()` call.

Move everything except the `glViewport()` call from `reshape()` to your `glutDisplayFunc()` callback:

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
}

void display()
{
    // clear framebuffer
    ...

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-0.001*zoomFactor, 0.001*zoomFactor, -0.001*zoomFactor, 0.001*zoomFactor, -100, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw stuff
    ...

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```